# How to concatenating rows with `group_by()`

Tags: r

I have a df like below:

[image]

I would like to concatenating rows with `group_by(Name)`. However my codes did not work as I want. Please find my output and codes below.

What should I do in order to get above results? Thanks.

[image]

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("Tom", "Tom", "Marry", "Ace"),
ClassA = c("A","B", "A", "B"), ClassB = c("B", NA, NA, NA), ClassC = c(NA, "C","C", NA)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))     

try<- df%>%
  group_by(Name) %>% summarise(across(everything(), str_c, collapse=""))%>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str_c` seems to be propagating the NAs rather than dropping them. Try

```
df %>%
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), function(x)paste(x[!is.na(x)], collapse=""))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

which produces

```
  Name  ClassA ClassB ClassC
  <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
1 Ace   B      ""     ""    
2 Marry A      ""     "C"   
3 Tom   AB     "B"    "C"
```

Comment: Just as a reference: It's actually mentioned in the docs: `Like most other R functions, missing values are "infectious": whenever a missing value is combined with another string the result will always be missing.` (see `?str_c`).

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively:

```
df %>%
  summarize(across(everything(), 
            ~paste0(coalesce(.x, ""), collapse = "")), 
            .by = Name)

# A tibble: 3 × 4
  Name  ClassA ClassB ClassC
  <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
1 Tom   AB     "B"    "C"   
2 Marry A      ""     "C"   
3 Ace   B      ""     ""
```

Note, `group_by` sorts the groups, while using the `.by` parameter of `summarize` (added with `dplyr 1.1.0`) does not. If you want it sorted, you could add `%>% arrange(Name)`.